# Adjust body width using img.onload

Tags: javascript

```
<img class="imgT" id="targ01" src='imgT/01.jpg' alt="img" onload="
var w = document.getElementById('targ01').width;
alert (w);
document.body.width = w;
">
```

css

```
.imgT{
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:84vh;
}
```

Alert shows `1024` (original width).

I need the actual width, after applaying css rule `max-height`. That is about 600px;

And then adjust the width of `body` according this value.

I can do everything using `window.onload` but that's too late. I need to change body `width` as early as possible.

Comment: If window is not loaded, there will be no targ01. My suggestion is to hide body (not sure if it is possible) and turn it to visible after do the task. Personally, I do a DIV inside body to work with as a body. I had the same problem with Flash and solved hiding everything until the first adjustments done.

Comment: @GustavoPinent, thanks for your suggestion. I think that `targ01` exists before `window.onload` because javascript reads its starting `width` before loading the entire page.

Comment: @GustavoPinent The `img` element should be accessible to the script as soon as the browser parses it, but the actual image most probably won't be loaded at that time.

Comment: I forgot to say: you should consider some issues about using onload in img. It will not fire if page is reloaded and img is already in cache. The element targ01 will be loaded, but not all body, not sure how browser deal with half body when executing the code...